# asyncjs callback not being executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, closures, async.js

I'm trying to merge the data from two JSON files (customer list) and then, create as many task as customers there are to be executed later via **async.js**

In order to have all the tasks array full, I'm controlling the end of the forEach with a promise:

```
var parsePromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
mongoDB.MongoClient.connect(dbURL, (error, db) => {
        originalData.forEach(function (element, index) {
            var restoredCustomer = Object.assign(element, backupData[index]);

            tasksArray.push((function (db, element) {
                return function () {
                    db.collection('customers').insert(element, function (error) {
                        if (error) {
                            console.error("Error: ", error);
                        }
                    })
                }
            })(db, restoredCustomer));

            forEachCounter--;
            if (forEachCounter === 0) {
                resolve(tasksArray);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Then, when the promise ends, I execute the **async.js** `parallel` method:

```
parsePromise.then(function (tasksArray) {
    async.parallel(tasksArray, (err, results) => {
        console.log("Operation completed successfully: ", results);
    })
})
```

The weird thing is that the code is working fine, and the inserts are being done on MongoDB, however, the `console.log("Operation completed successfully: ", results);` placed in the `parallel` callback is never shown.

Comment: That's because you're not pushing any promises in to `tasksArray`.

Comment: If you're in NodeJS land, there's not much reason not to embrance ES6. This can be simplified a lot using arrow functions and `async`/`await`.

Comment: @IvanRubinson I know that I can do it with ES6, but I want to test with async.js. Related to your other comment, why I need to push the a promise to `taskArray`? The promise is related to the `forEach`, not to the functions to be executed in batch (inserts)

Comment: async.js can't run your callback until all promises in the array you give it are settled. But what you're giving it is not an array of promises.

Comment: But the array I'm creating has no promises, the promise is in order to no execute the `parallel` method until the `forEach` loop has ended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var parsePromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
mongoDB.MongoClient.connect(dbURL, (error, db) => {
        originalData.forEach(function (element, index) {
            var restoredCustomer = Object.assign(element, backupData[index]);
             tasksArray.push(function(cb){
                  db.collection('customers').insert(restoredCustomer, function (error) {
                        if (error) return cb(err);
                        cb();
                    })
             });

            forEachCounter--;
            if (forEachCounter === 0) {
                resolve(tasksArray);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

According to async js documentation
https://caolan.github.io/async/global.html
tasks arguments in parallel function in async.js must be AsyncFunction.
AsyncFunction requires to have the final parameter which is a callback. The structure of the callback follows the standard of function(err, args).

Also you can try simplifying your code to:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  mongoDB.MongoClient.connect(dbURL, (error, db) => {
        if (error) return reject(error);
        resolve(db);
  });
}).then(db => {
  var tasksArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i != originalData.length; ++i){
    var restoredCustomer = Object.assign(originalData[i], backupData[index]);
    tasksArray.push(function(cb){
      db.collection('customers').insert(restoredCustomer, function (error) {
        if (error) return cb(err);
        cb();
      })
    });
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    async.parallel(tasksArray, (err, results) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        resolve(results)
    })
  })
})
```